# What is the best way to inject a class of a child type with Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Is it just to provide the child type in the module ? or is there a more direct way eg by using constructor injection with some parameter ?

```
@Module
class TestModule() {

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideDummy(): Dummy = DummyChild()

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dummy: Dumy

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how it needs to be done. The Module provides components that can be injected.

In the above case `TestModule` is the module which can provide `DummyChild`. It becomes a complicated if the constructor of `DummyChild` required a parameter. In that case the parameter needs to be injected as well.

```
@Module
class TestModule() {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDummy(Context context): Dummy = DummyChild(context)
}
```

In the above case, `context` needs to be provided as well. You should have an exposed Provides method that can provide Context.

Answer (score 0):

> or is there a more direct way eg by using constructor injection with some parameter ?

Absolutely!

```
@Module
class TestModule() {

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideDummy(): Dummy = DummyChild() // bad, we construct it ourselves!

}
```

You should let Dagger care about where the object comes from, so calling the constructor is usually not a good idea (unless this is really what you want). The proper way to bind an implementation is by using a `@Provides` method and requesting the child, directly returning it, or just using the `@Binds` annotation which will do effectively the same, but possibly more optimized than `@Provides`.

```
@Module
class TestModule() {

  @Provides
  fun provideDummy(implementation : DummyChild): Dummy = implementation // better!

  // or with @Binds

  @Binds
  abstract fun provideDummy(implementation : DummyChild): Dummy // also good

}

@Singleton class DummyChild @Inject constructor()
```

Notice that I removed the `@Singleton` from the methods, as this is usually an implementation detail of `DummyChild`, rather than the interface, but you can of course still add it to the method if you wish to do so.